# “Ambiguous Reference To” Error after updating to Swift 3 JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift3, anyobject

I've updated my code to Swift 3 protocol, and this is the last error I get that I can't solve in regards to JSON.

This is my code:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: targetURL!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {

                if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? [String : AnyObject]? {

                    if let youtubeVideoImageURL = items![0]["snippet"]!!["thumbnails"]!!["high"]!!["url"]!! as? String {

                        self.youtubeJsonImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(youtubeVideoImageURL)
                        self.youtubeImageURLHidden.text = youtubeVideoImageURL
                        self.youtubeJsonImage.clipsToBounds = true

                    } else {

                        let youtubeVideoImageURL = items![0]["snippet"]!!["thumbnails"]!!["standard"]!!["url"]!! as? String
                        self.youtubeJsonImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(youtubeVideoImageURL!)
                        self.youtubeImageURLHidden.text = youtubeVideoImageURL
                        self.youtubeJsonImage.clipsToBounds = true


                    }

                    let youtubeLikeCount = items![0]["statistics"]!!["commentCount"]!!
                    let itermediarytext = youtubeLikeCount as! String
                    let numberText = Int(itermediarytext)
                    let finalText = self.suffixNumber(numberText!)
                    self.youtubeVideoLikes.text = "\(finalText) comments"

                    self.determineBool()


                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
            self.stopAnimating()

        }

    })

    // Start the request
    task.resume()

}
```

And this is the error line with Ambiguous Reference,

```
if let youtubeVideoImageURL = items![0]["snippet"]!!["thumbnails"]!!["high"]!!["url"]!! as? String {
```

I've also looked through other stack overflow solutions but they don't seem to apply to this type of data structure.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Swift 3 you should use dictionary type `[String: Any]` instead of `[String: AnyObject]`

Comment: Still same error with change.

Comment: I suspect that your targetURL type is `NSURL` but it should be `URL`

Comment: It already is type URL.

Comment: (Item.first as? [String: Any])?["snippet"] and so on

Comment: Also your cast to dict should be a cast to [Any] at the line above that

Comment: Tried adding the  
(Item.first as? [String: Any])?["snippet"]!!["thumbnails"]!!["high"]!!["url"]!! , but still fails to cast to unrelated type.

Comment: You need to do the same for the intermediaries

Comment: Snippet can be Any type so you needto cast it also

Comment: Cast from '(key: String, value: Any)?' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails, even when I apply it to intermediaries

Comment: Cast it to optional or unwrap it first

Comment: Are you recommending me to have it setup like this? (items?.first as! [String: Any]!)["snippet"]!(items!.first as? [String: Any])?["thumbnails"]! ???

Comment: Forget about chaining it like SwiftyJSON, use guard to unwrap each level of your dictionary or array of Any

Comment: can you post an example please, the way I learned JSON, was by chaining.

Comment: Once you understand the process you can start trying to daisy chain it